# android sqlite update online with updating the app and affecting user inputted data

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I using SQLite as my database.

Using the app, the user can save some item on the database.

But I would like also to update the database from time to time.

The problem is how can I update the database without affecting the user inserted data and in a manner that it will download the new database online and not by updating the app itself.

Comment: When you say you want to update the database, you mean deploying a new version online, so that the app can download it?

Comment: What do you mean by "update the database"? Can you give an example?

Comment: @Code-Guru update means i will add an additional contents to the SQLite database.

Comment: @Merlevede actually I do not know how it will be deployed. The problem is how can I update the database without updating the app itself.

Comment: I guess the answer speaks for itself. You would need to update the database without updating the app!!! You can make the app download it from internet... I guess I'm not getting the issue here.

Comment: @Merlevede to have any idea how? to have any tutorials?

Comment: Do you know the concept of **syncing**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since my comment is large, I'll post it as an answer.

You won't find any tutorial showing exactly what you're trying to accomplish, because what you need is somewhat complex (but not difficult)

First approach:

1. You need your app to query some webservice to find out if there's a newer version of the database, and if there is, download it
2. The database must be saved in some temporary location, then you transfer all the users saved data to the new database, and finally replace the apps database with the new database (already updated with user's data)

Another approach would be:

1. Make your app query some webservice to find if the database needs to be updated.
2. If yes, download the SQL commands to modify the database structure.

Comment: Google how to make an 'http request in Android', you'll find tons of information.